# Function copies objects in JavaScript by calling itself, Need help understanding the logic

Tags: javascript, for-loop, logic

I found this JavaScript code for copying Objects, the code is doing what it's suppose to do, but what I don't understand is when the function call itself; how come `newObject` in the first iteration desn't loose its value, it should be overwritten when the function called itself and created a new `newObject` ? does that mean that when a function call itself it still keeps a copy of the first `newObject` created before it called itself?

```
const o = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  obj: {
    key: 'key',
  },
}

const o2 = o

o2.a = 'new value'

// o and o2 reference the same object
console.log(o.a)

// this shallow-copies o into o3
const o3 = Object.assign({}, o)

// deep copy
function deepCopy(obj) {
  // check if vals are objects
  // if so, copy that object (deep copy)
  // else return the value
  const keys = Object.keys(obj)

  const newObject = {}

  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const key = keys[i]
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      newObject[key] = deepCopy(obj[key])
    } else {
      newObject[key] = obj[key]
    }
  }

  return newObject
}

const o4 = deepCopy(o)

o.obj.key = 'new key!'
console.log(o4.obj.key)
```

Comment: The newObject is the value that is assigned to a property of the "parent" newObject, so you get a nested object.

Comment: Every call to a function (including the recursive calls) creates a new context for local variables. The new recursive function call has its very own private `newObject`, distinct from the value in the function that called it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive functions can be confusing. A few well placed `console.log()`s or running the code in a debugger can really help. The function makes a `newObject` for the original object and *each child object in the object*. As the recursion unwinds it sets the property in the parent to the result of the recursive call on the child.

You can see the effect in the console.logs here:

```js
const o = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  obj: {
    key: 'key',
    deeper: {one: 1, two: 2}
  },
}


// deep copy
function deepCopy(obj) {
  console.log("deep copy of: ", obj)
  const keys = Object.keys(obj)

  const newObject = {}

  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const key = keys[i]
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      console.log("setting child of", key, "to:")
      newObject[key] = deepCopy(obj[key])
    } else {
      newObject[key] = obj[key]
    }
  }

  return newObject
}

console.log("starting with")
const o4 = deepCopy(o)
```

Each of the lines starting with `deep copy of` indicates a newly created `newObject` in a recursive call, but the only `newObject` returned is the first one — all the others get set as children.

Comment: *"Recursive functions can be confusing."* ++